# Bundler cant find gem installed on system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I'm having a problem with one of my gems and I need to test my code with a rails app, I usually do this by adding a symlink in vendor/plugins but I think what I want to do needs it to be required as a gem not a plugin.

I've used bundler in the gem so I can build it with `rake build`, or install it using `rake install`, I've done a `rake install` and I get a lovely green text message saying that my gem has been installed. So I swapped over to my Rails app and added `gem 'gemname', '1.0.0pre'` to my Gemfile (matching the version I just installed) and ran a `bundle install` and it just hangs and then throws up and error saying it cant find the gem in any of my sources.

I've already run through making sure that I was using the right rvm ruby when installing the gem etc... and I'm at a loss as to why this wont work. Bundler normally has no problems with gems I already have installed.

Answer (score 0):

Bundler only knows about gems from sources specified in the Gemfile.

Put your gem in vendor/gems and then specify the location in your Gemfile like this:

```
gem "yourgem", :path => "vendor/yourgem"
```

Your gem must have a yourgem.gemspec or bundler still won't find it.

Alternatively, you can reference a git project.
e.g.

```
gem "rails", :git => "git://github.com/rails/rails.git"
```

Then run bundle install.